# How to assign multiple taxonmoy to custom post?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on to create custom posts from frontend. Post values are inserting correctly but when i am trying to assign a custom taxonomy to this post then its not working and not showing assigned taxonomy terms in admin. I had done this manytime but not getting what's issue. I have tried this to implode the values and tries to assign a single taxonomy term also. But not get success. This is my code to assign custom taxonomy term

```
$id = wp_insert_post(array('post_title'=>$title, 'post_type'=>'associations', 'post_content'=>$generalDesc,'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($associationIndustry as $industry)
{   
    wp_set_post_terms($id, $industry, 'industries', true); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code :

In place of 39 and 52 set your category id

if your `$associationIndustry` is having the same array you can directly pass that variable without foreach loop

```
// the number is category ID
wp_set_post_terms( $id, array( 39 , 52 ), 'industries' );
```

Comment: i have tried this without foreach also but not working